# Java Pattern Multiline

Tags: java, regex

Hi i would like to find that code in HTML

```
{%foreach damagePhotos : photo%}
    <img src="{%=photo}" alt="" width="320" height="200"/>
{%endforeach%}
```

My regexp is:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\{\\%foreach\\s(.*)\\s:\\s(.*)\\%\\}\\s(.*)\\s\\{\\%endforeach\\%\\}",Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(parsedHtml);
```

And everything work fine untile i've got many of that pattern i html :(

for example:

```
<p>
    {%foreach carPhotos : photo%}
    <img src="{%=photo}" alt="" width="320" height="200"/>
    {%endforeach%}
</p>
<p>
    {%foreach damagePhotos : photo%}
    <img src="{%=photo}" alt="" width="320" height="200"/>
    {%endforeach%}
</p>
```

Then mather find one match and group(1) is:

```
carPhotos : photo%}    <img src="{%=photo}" alt="" width="320" height="200"/>    {%endforeach%}</p><p>    {%foreach damagePhotos
```

What is wrong with my regexp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` is greedy, meaning it will span across multiple foreach groups.

try adding a reluctant qualifier, i.e. `.*?`

Also, be aware of the [limitations of using regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: `Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\{\\%foreach\\s(\\w+)\\s:\\s(\\w+)\\%\\}\\s(.*?)\\s\\{\\%endforeach\\%\\}",Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(parsedHtml);` works fine! thx

Comment: @paweb on an unrelated note, I think you intended to use `Pattern.DOTALL`, not `Pattern.MULTILINE`